# Search and copy files between drives

Tags: ssh, filesystem, drive, transfer

I am using ubuntu in installed on my external drive is there a way to transfer files between my native drive (Ubuntu - external drive) and in my windows drive (my laptop's drive)?

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification, you have the Ubuntu operating system and your files on an external hard drive, and you want to transfer files from said external hard drive to a Windows computer. Provided the Ubuntu disk is written in ext4 (the file system), try these [application on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows).